# A compact space whose proper compact subspaces are finite

Tags: general-topology, compactness

[A recent deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965015/infinite-compact-space-whose-only-compact-subsets-are-itself-and-finite-subsets) asked:

> Are there infinite compact spaces whose only compact subsets are finite or itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  Suppose $X$ is such a space.  Since closed subsets of compact spaces are themselves compact, every closed proper subset of $X$ is compact and therefore finite.

Now let $S$ be an arbitrary infinite subset of $X$ and let $\mathcal C$ be an open cover of $S$. Suppose $G$ is any element of $\mathcal C$.  Then  $S\setminus G$ is finite because it is the intersection of $S$ and the closed (and therefore finite) set $X\setminus G$.  The finite set $S\setminus G$ is easily covered by a finite subcover $\mathcal C'\subset \mathcal C$, so  $\mathcal C'\cup\{G\}$ is a finite subcover of $S$.  This shows that the infinite set $S$ is compact, a contradiction.

Comment: Alternate sequential argument:  choose an injective sequence in $X$ that misses at least two points in $X$.  The union of a convergent subsequence and its limit is a proper, infinite, compact subset.

Comment: Thanks, why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be an infinite compact space, and choose an injective sequence in $X$ that misses at least two points in $X$.  Then the union of a convergent subsequence and its limit is a proper, infinite, compact subset.